# java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting the java.lang.VerifyError, I have tried everything, I have changed the gradles because the first error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError, that was solved and after that i get the java.lang VerifyError. I see in the class still that it says update the sdk, i have changed in the gradle the compileSdkVersion,  buildToolsVersion to 25 and i have changed the dependencies to version 25
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KyVl.png)
[The class that gives the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDRdy.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it on a different machine with a new android installation. Maybe this works.

In the past i had some trouble with cache in Android Studio. I tried cleaning it but only after i moved my files to another system it gave me an error about what was wrong with the code! This error did never show up on the original system.